# Grails DetachedCriteria using 'where' throw SyntaxErrorException

Tags: mysql, hibernate, grails

I am trying to do the next select:

---

```
ArrayList<Personal> personalAuxList = new ArrayList<Personal>()
def campaigns = Campaign.findAllByEntidad(entidadInstance,[sort: "fechaFin", order: "desc"])
//Here a declare a DetachedCriteria using where method of domain class
def notificacionesQuery = Notificacion.where {
    orden.linea.propuesta.campaign in campaigns
}
//For each persona from a search result done before     
for(Personal person : result.results){
    if(!personalAuxList.contains(person)){
        //I add a condition to query creating new one
        def notisOfPersonalQuery = notificacionesQuery.where {
            personal == person
        }
        //Fail in this line when i list the result
        def notificaciones = notisOfPersonalQuery.list()
        notificaciones = notificaciones.sort{it.orden.linea.fin}.reverse()
        notisOfPersonal.put(person.id, notificaciones.empty ? null : notificaciones.first())
        personalAuxList.add(person)
    }
}
```

---

That works fine on local, but when i upload the war, start failing in the server:

---

**Class:** com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException

**Message:** You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ') and this_.personal_id=6616' at line 1

---

Trace:

---

```
Line | Method

->>  411 | handleNewInstance    in com.mysql.jdbc.Util
```

---

```
|    386 | getInstance          in     ''
|   1052 | createSQLException . in com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError
|   4098 | checkErrorPacket     in com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO
|   4030 | checkErrorPacket . . in     ''
|   2490 | sendCommand          in     ''
|   2651 | sqlQueryDirect . . . in     ''
|   2677 | execSQL              in com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl
|   2134 | executeInternal . .  in com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement
|   2300 | executeQuery         in     ''
|     97 | executeQuery . . . . in org.apache.commons.dbcp.DelegatingPreparedStatement
|    671 | doCall               in grails.gorm.DetachedCriteria$_list_closure2
|    934 | doCall . . . . . . . in grails.gorm.DetachedCriteria$_withPopulatedQuery_closure9
|    669 | doCall               in org.grails.datastore.gorm.GormStaticApi$_withDatastoreSession_closure20
|    302 | execute . . . . . .  in org.grails.datastore.mapping.core.DatastoreUtils
|     34 | execute              in org.grails.datastore.gorm.AbstractDatastoreApi
|    668 | withDatastoreSession in org.grails.datastore.gorm.GormStaticApi
|    916 | withPopulatedQuery   in grails.gorm.DetachedCriteria
|    667 | list . . . . . . . . in     ''
|    666 | list                 in     ''
|    301 | search . . . . . . . in com.publidirecta.PersonalController
^    722 | run                  in java.lang.Thread
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solve it finally, on local i got campaigns in the DDBB but on real server no, so i change the code to add a condition if there's no campaigns:

---

```
ArrayList<Personal> personalAuxList = new ArrayList<Personal>()
def campaigns = Campaign.findAllByEntidad(entidadInstance,[sort: "fechaFin", order: "desc"])
if (campaigns != null && campaigns.size() > 0) {
    def notificacionesQuery = Notificacion.where {
        orden.linea.propuesta.campaign in campaigns
    } 
    for(Personal person : result.results){
        if(!personalAuxList.contains(person)){
            def notisOfPersonalQuery = notificacionesQuery.where {
                personal == person
            }
            def notificaciones = notisOfPersonalQuery.list()
            notificaciones = notificaciones.sort{it.orden.linea.fin}.reverse()
            notisOfPersonal.put(person.id, notificaciones.empty ? null : notificaciones.first())
            personalAuxList.add(person)
        }
    }
}
```